# Import MATLAB file in React

Tags: reactjs, matlab

I want to import a Matlab file to my React.js project.

```
{14,10,3,21,3,... } // 13845841 elements
```

First I tried to convert it into JSON file.
but the file size increased too much (from 1.6 MB .mat file to 40 MB JSON file).
(I used jsonencode() function)

When I try to get data from the imported JSON,
React crashes.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I tried slicing the data in half (20 MB JSON file) and it worked without error (it took time but affordable)

Do I need to increase memory size? or Do I need to try another method since using a 40 MB JSON file is insane?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that what your MATLAB file looks like? `{}` with numbers in between and nothing else? Do you import this into MATLAB by running the file like a script?

Comment: If so, it becomes a cell array with 1x1 matrices in MATLAB, which is hugely wasteful. Replace the `{}` braces with `[]` in your file, then you’ll have a normal array, which will be simpler when exported to JSON. Or remove the braces altogether, then you’ll have CSV file, no need for MATLAB at all.